# how to draw a circle in video

Tags: c++, opencv, video, opencv3.0

im trying to draw a circle in a video from my webcam i using this function

```
 cv::circle(cap,points(1,0),3,cv::Scalar(255,255,255),-1);
```

i found it in a document but i don't know why its't work i edit my code many time but its still give my error that's my full code i using opencv3

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>  
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video file for reading

    if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
    {
         cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
         return -1;
    }

    //cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 300); //start the video at 300ms

    double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); //get the frames per seconds of the video

     cout << "Frame per seconds : " << fps << endl;

    namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"

    while(1)
    {
        Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

        if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
                        cout << "Cannot read the frame from video file" << endl;
                       break;
        }

        imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

        cv::circle(cap,points(1,0),3,cv::Scalar(255,255,255),-1);

        if(waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30 ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
       {
                cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl; 
                break; 
       }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Draw circle on frame (and not cap), and move the imshow after circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`circle` accepts a `Mat` object, not a `VideoCapture` object. So you need to draw the circle on `frame`.
Also you need to show the image after you actually draw the circle.

So replace the `imshow` / `circle` part of your code with:

```
...
cv::circle(frame, points(1,0), 3, cv::Scalar(255,255,255), -1);
imshow("MyVideo", frame);
...
```